# FileOpenPicker opening twice on doubleclick

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

Examples always show something like this:

```
private async void openBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();     
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();  
}
```

But if the user clicks twice it will open two picker windows. Is that really the right way?

Comment: Use `PickSingleFileAndContinue()` instead?

Comment: Or check this one https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1179716/Extending-Content-Message-Dialog-Class-in-UWP-to-A

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options to solve this issue, first may be to use *Semaphore/SemaphoreSlim* and await it. Second - at the begginging of the event unsubscribe it, do work, then subscribe:

```
private async void openBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.Clik -= openBtn_Click;
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();     
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    // do smth
    button.Clik += openBtn_Click;
```